# Ember Data update POST when it should be PUT

Tags: ajax, http, post, ember.js, put

I'm working on an Ember.js app. I have an update function, part of an ObjectController.

The function should save my updated model, however when I call `save();` it sends a POST request not a PUT request. (Tested in Chrome.)

Why would that happen?  How can I make sure a PUT request is sent for updates?

Here is my code:

```
customer = this.get('model');
customer.set('name', 'New name');
customer.save();
```

For extra reference, when I log the "dirtyType" with `console.log( customer.get('dirtyType') );` it says "updated".

Any help very much appreciated!

### UPDATE

I've adjusted the sample code above to make it clearer, I am NOT creating a new model and wanting to use PUT. I have an existing model that I need to update.

Comment: Ok a little more information, when I get the model "isNew" is true.

To get round this I have set "isNew" to false and I get the PUT request I was expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all of your help guys, however I have found the issue and it is ridiculously silly.

The API I have been using had a new flag "is_new" and that had been added to the model and was overwriting the "isNew" property.

Causing Ember (and me) to get very confused.

I've tweaked the API and all is good in the world!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your workaround is correct in the land of PUT vs POST.

TL;DR PUT should define the resource (by Request-URI), but we don't do that during creation, so we shouldn't be using a POST.  Override the create/save if you need this for your server, instead of hacking the `isNew` property, which may come back to bite you.

#### Put

> 9.6 PUT
>
> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>      supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already
>      existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a
>      modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the
>      Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is
>      capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user
>      agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI. If a
>      new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent
>      via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified,
>      either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent
>      to indicate successful completion of the request. If the resource
>      could not be created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate
>      error response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the
>      problem. The recipient of the entity MUST NOT ignore any Content-*
>      (e.g. Content-Range) headers that it does not understand or implement
>      and MUST return a 501 (Not Implemented) response in such cases.
>
> If the request passes through a cache and the Request-URI identifies
>      one or more currently cached entities, those entries SHOULD be
>      treated as stale. Responses to this method are not cacheable.
>
> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is
>      reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a
>      POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed
>      entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to
>      some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations.
>      In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed
>      with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the
>      server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.
>      If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI,

#### Custom Adapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record, { includeId: true });

    //return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), "POST", { data: data });
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), "PUT", { data: data });
  },


  updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record);

    var id = get(record, 'id');
    // you could do the same here, but it's even more incorrect
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "PUT", { data: data });
  },
});
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify, I believe I have read this correctly however: in the app I `POST` to the API to **create** the model, then later I **update** the model and when I save I am expecting a `PUT` request to be made. However that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the model was created with createRecord, and thus has `isNew == true` and you call `save()` the expected behavior is `POST`. Once the record has been persisted, and it is changed, and thus `isDirty == true` but `isNew == false` then the `save()` will be a `PUT`.

This is described in the [Models Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/).

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The record has already been persisted. To be clear, I have a list of customers, I create a new customer and save. I know the save is persisting because I can see the new record in the database. I then proceed to the individual customer page, make a change and then save. And that point I get a POST not a PUT...

Comment: Taking your thoughts a little further, @Kevin Bullaughey, do I need to manually mark isNew as false when the createRecord save promise is fulfilled or should that happen automatically?

Comment: isNew and isDirty are ready only properties, so you can't manually change these. They should be automatically updated by ember data. Are you sure you're not somehow creating a new record? Or maybe you are sending the data to your backend, but ember thinks the call is failing and thus the model hasn't entered the saved state? What do you get when you look at `customer.get('currentState.stateName')`? If it has been saved it should be `root.loaded.saved` but if you get `root.loaded.created.uncommitted` then you haven't saved it yet.